# База данных целиком в памяти

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

База данных PostgreSQL имеет небольшой размер - порядка 1 Гб. И этот размер растет медленно. А скорость работы критична. Вопрос в том, как поместить всю базу целиком в память для ее ускорения. Интересно также, как сделать то же самое и с MySQL (про запас).

Answer (score 4):

Решение, которое подойдет и для PostgreSQL, и для MySQL, - это создание диска в памяти, и работа базы с этого диска. Правда, при таком подходе возникает противоречие между надежностью (а это одно из самых главных достоинств PostgreSQL) и скоростью.

Диск в памяти делается в Linux просто.

```
$ mkdir /mnt/tmpfs/
$ chmod 777 /mnt/tmpfs/
$ mount -t tmpfs -o size=размер tmpfs /mnt/tmpfs/
```

И после этого с диском можно работать. Но надо помнить, что это реально память, и при любом сбое все, что там есть будет потеряно. Поэтому придется заводить какое-либо резервирование.

Comment: ..требую продолжения, какое лучше резервирование использовать, и как? (допустим, для mysql)

Comment: mysqldump -B base_name > /home/vasya/basedump.sql и в crontab раз в 5 минут.А лучше my.cnf и настроить буферизацию. Но снимать дамп в равно надо, хотябы раз в неделю, если база критичноя то и раз в сутки.

Comment: Использовать такие методы для не-временных таблиц (которые должны переживать перезагрузку) — наркоманство.Для ускорения БД за счёт памяти во всех нормальных СУБД есть кеши (на это тут уже указывали). Для ускорения любых дисковых операций за счёт памяти в Linux есть дисковый кэш в памяти.Для временных таблиц в mysql есть специальный движёк хранения хранящий данные в ОЗУ. Так-же есть широкий спектр in-memory хранилищ, правда большинство из них no-sql.

Answer (score 4):

Перед тем, как помещать всю базу в память, есть смысл понастраивать отдельные параметры в конфигурации PostgreSQL. Хорошее руководство здесь: [Tuning Your PostgreSQL Server](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server).

Comment: То же самое можно сделать и в MySQL. Укажите в настройках размеры буферов так, чтобы их хватило на всю базу.

Answer (score 3):

Зачем вам создавать диск в памяти? Это очень ненадежно.Увеличьте shared_buffers в конфиге до 2Гб (с запасом) и у вас вся база залезет в память.Увеличте также checkpoint_segments, чтобы база пореже сбрасывала данные на диск. Если что, то они не потеряются, просто база будет дольше стартовать в случае краха, будет больше накатывать WAL-логов.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в PostgreSQL это делается, а в MariaDB есть движок для этого. Движок называется Memory Storage Engine.

Если у вас большой проект - рассматривайте возможности перехода на Drizzle.

Comment: кстати посмотрите, может быть этот движок можно прикрутить и к другим ДБ, но у меня есть сомнения либо ищите собственные реализации для этого ПО.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошая рускоязычная документация для улучшения производительности postgres есть [на сайте postgrespro](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/performance-tips)

Перед помещением данных в память лучше проверить, что все запросы достаточно хорошо оптимизированы. Если до этого не было оптимизации запросов и индексов, то может получиться, что и в памяти будет не быстро работать.