# Атомарная подмена папок в Linux

Tags: linux, файлы, файловая-система, обработка

Есть несколько скриптов, слушающих разные порты. Все эти скрипты пишут в одну и туже директорию, допустим /1/. В момент времени N(не более 20 минут) запускается еще один скрипт, который перемещает все эти файлы в директорию, допустим /2/, а затем начинается их обработка в директории 2. В момент перемещения файлов из директории 1 в директорию 2, в директорию 1 могут поступать новые файлы. Совсем недавно стало проблемой огромное количество файлов(несколько десятков тысяч за 20 минут). Обработка много времени не занимает, файлы хранятся потом по своим параметрам 2 недели, после удаляются. Интервал запуска забора файлов сократить нельзя. Исторически всё работает именно так.

### Вопрос:

Можно ли как то атомарно поменять директории местами, то есть пустая 2 становится 1, а директория 1 с файлами становится 2. Атомарно, конечно не в рамках команды процессора, а без ущерба системе и работе скриптов. Может есть варианты как-то с inode заморочиться? Вот ну никак не хочется всё это переписывать. Так что любые советы в этой ситуации приветствуются. Есть ещё идея не использовать директорию 2. А обрабатывать сразу всё из директории 1, но тогда, наверное, придется устанавливать экслюзивную блокировку на каждый файл в директории 1, для скриптов пишущих в неё эти файлы.

Comment: вы не указали существенный момент — процессы продолжают держать файлы открытыми между атомарными операциями записи?

Comment: Мне кажется должно получиться сделать символьную ссылку /1/ и менять путь, куда она ведет, то на /2/ то на /3/. В этом случае скрипты должны дописать открытые файлы, а новые файлы будут падать в другую директорию, т.е. ничего не сломается.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нет, данные пришли, мы открыли файл, записали их на диск в директорию 1, файл закрылся. затем вмомент х все файлы, накопившиеся в 1 **перенесли** в директорию 2 и запустили их обработку в директории 2(может возникнуть ситуация, когда при записи файла в директорию 1, работает перенос файлов в 2, на практике всё норм). Во время обработки файл открылся, прочитался, обработался, закрылся, в зависимости от данных в нем - перенесли файл из директории 2 в директорию /3/dir1/...

Comment: @AlexeyReytsman интересная идея, попробую на практике.

Comment: @AlexeyReytsman не совсем всё хорошо в случае, если папка 2 не успела до конца обработаться, а символьную ссылку мы уже поменяли. но в моём случае всё подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. если пишущие процессы **не оставляют** каталог `1` текущим («текущий каталог» — это свойство процесса, изменяемое вызовом функции [chdir()/fchdir()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir)) между фактами создания новых файлов, то подойдёт решение, предложенное [Alexey Reytsman](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/230562) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606636/?noredirect=1#comment827267_606636). для «переключения каталогов»:

   1. создайте новый каталог с произвольным именем (например, текущей меткой времени)
   2. создайте символическую ссылку `1`, указывающую на этот каталог:

      ```
      $ ln -snf имя-нового-каталога 1
      ```

      при каждом выполнении этой команды (благодаря опциям `-n` и `-f`) ссылка просто будет менять место, на которое она указывает.

      в первый раз, когда `1` у вас всё ещё будет являться каталогом, а не ссылкой, надо будет перед этим произвести переименование (`1` в `2`) «старым» способом.
   3. то же самое можно проделать и для каталога `2`, превратив его в ссылку (указывающую на «реальный» каталог, созданный на предыдущей итерации двадцать минут назад).
   4. не забывайте удалять «реальные» каталоги по окончанию их обработки.
2. если пишущие процессы **оставляют** каталог `1` текущим между фактами создания новых файлов, то большей «атомарности» можно добиться, манипулируя не каталогом, а файлами в каталоге, перемещая их из каталога `1` в каталог `2`:

   ```
   $ find 1 -type f -exec mv {} 2 \;
   ```

   уточнения:

   1. каталоги `1` и `2` для «гладкости» процесса должны находиться в пределах одной файловой системы.
   2. для большей «атомарности» эту файловую систему имеет смысл [держать в памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/338807/178576) ([*tmpfs*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs#Linux)).
   3. если между открытием и закрытием файла пишущим процессом может проходить какое-то существенное время, имеет смысл после переноса файлов в каталог `2`, но перед началом их обработки, делать задержку, превышающую это максимальное время «раздумий» пишущего процесса.

Comment: Не проще logrotate напустить на них? А вызов rename насколько я помню атомарно выполняется.

Comment: @0andriy, *Не проще logrotate* — мне кажется, использование *logrotate* будет скорее **усложнением**, нежели **упрощением**. но если вы изложите свой вариант решения с использованием *logrotate*, я буду только «за».

Answer (score 0):

Выскажусь не по вопросу, а по идеологии задачи :-)

Писать принятые данные в кучу файлов (наверное ещё - с датами и временем в имени?), перемещать потом их в каталог обработки, там обрабатывать... Это даже не Windows... Это прям навевает воспоминания о DOS/3.1 :-)

Мало того, что такой подход добавляет кучу геммороя системным администраторам (Скрипты!!!), так он ещё и очень ненадёжен.

Может быть всё-таки попробовать использовать pipe или системные очереди сообщений? Никаких проблем с синхронизацией производитель/потребитель, никакого мусора в ФС, а самое главное - НАДЖЁЖНО!

Comment: Ну вот уж очень не хочется всё переписывать. А так вы правы - всё работает еще с очень древних времен. Работает и никто не трогал, разве что систему только обновляли. Но обновили источники информации(писатели) и теперь всё встряло. Проверенный вчера подход придал скорости, вроде как бы пока всё устраивает. Но чутье подсказывает что всё это придётся переделывать рано или поздно.